# Setting Super Simple View Engine Sections in from nested master pages

Tags: nancy, viewengine

I'm building a web application and am using Nancy and Super Simple view engine to render the content for the user. Since a lot of the pages have the same layout (headers, sidemenu, ect.), I have seperated reusable contents in a master page.

Currently I have

```
--Root_file (Master page)
   --Home
   --Products
   --Contact
   --Account (Master page)
     --Overview
     --Manage
     --Post
```

All files under root_file have a `@Master['root_file.html']` reference. All files under Account have a `@Master['account.html']`.

Now my problem is, for Manage under Account I want to set a js-script as an additional header. I figured, by referring to the tag in the top-level Master Page, I would be able to add the js through  reference.

Here's an overview.

```
Root_file.html
<head>
    <title>Nice little title.</title>
    @Partial['PartialView/header_references.html']
    @Section['Additional_headers'];
</head>
<body>
    @Section['Content'];
</body>

account.html
@Master['root_file.html']

@Section['Content']
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            @Partial['PartialView/side_menu.html']
            <div class="col p-3">
                @Section['Inner_content'];
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@EndSection

manage.html
@Master['account/overview.html']
@Section['Additional_headers']
    <script src="../../../Content/scripts/file-upload.js"></script>
@EndSection
```

I was hoping that I could set `@Section[Additional_headers]` through the nested master page, but the result doesn't reflect my hope.

Am I doing something wrong, or isnt it possible to set sections like this?

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question and I figured you got this answered elsewhere but perhaps someone else has the same issue.
I ended up wrapping the placeholders of the top master page with new ones in the subpage. It's anything but pretty but it gets the job done.

In your html page you reference

```
@Section['Additional_headers']
```

Instead you can reference this in your sub master page wrapped in a new placeholder like:

```
@Section['Additional_headers']
@Section['Sub_Additional_headers']
@EndSection
```

You can then reference this new section in any underlying html pages like this

```
@Section['Sub_Additional_headers']
<label>This is in a nested master page</label>
@EndSection
```

To reuse your example above it would look something like this

```
Root_file.html
<head>
    <title>Nice little title.</title>
    @Partial['PartialView/header_references.html']
    @Section['Additional_headers'];
</head>
<body>
@Section['Content'];
</body>

account.html
@Master['root_file.html']

@Section['Additional_headers']
@Section['Sub_Additional_headers']
@EndSection

@Section['Content']
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        @Partial['PartialView/side_menu.html']
        <div class="col p-3">
            @Section['Inner_content'];
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@EndSection

manage.html
@Master['account/overview.html']
@Section['Sub_Additional_headers']
<script src="../../../Content/scripts/file-upload.js"></script>
@EndSection
```